# Android Emulator is poor

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Why my Android Emulator is horrible?! I installed KVM and others components to use Android Emulator, but this is unusable. Help, please.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2
KERNEL: 4.8
PROC: i7 5500U 2.4 GHz

[image]

Comment: Might help if you explained "horrible" and "unusable"

Comment: for example, that's screen in question, it's very hard read the text explain about permissions.

Comment: Change scaling on screen?

Comment: Where I'll change scalling?

Comment: Looks like the issue is in picture scaling - I've seen this in cases when GPU driver fails and emulator either falls back to software rendering or silently fails to apply image resizing shader.
Could you please run the emulator in a terminal with -verbose flag and post the output here?

Comment: @MT-Wizard I'm using x86 VD. I ran with -verbose flag and the output is very large. To see that, access [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xT0hWT-ogrseBuL4zZaqhYtEtziHkCRlSvyIl79J6rw/edit?usp=sharing). For help, I activate my dedicated GPU (nvidia 920m) and was well results. But, withi intel, the results is the same [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r4zN.png).

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling hardware acceleration. And, use Intel HA. You can choose that while creating your VD.

Comment: So, I enabled hardware acceleration in my system's BIOS, a curiosity, tested Android Emulator on Microsoft Windows and that works.

Comment: Which type of AVD have you created? Is it ARM or x86?

Comment: I always create ARM VDs. I always mark the checkbox to use hardware acceleration while creating or configuring the VD.

Comment: I use x86, because Google APIs are available only this abi and recently is possible use Google Play Store, but only on x86 abi.

Comment: When you create an ARM device, Android Studio shows that big red warning for a good reason - emulating ARM system on x86 is 10-100 times slower compared to simply running an x86 virtual machine.
Also, ARM emulation doesn't really emulate ARM as it is - there's no simple way to make it behave the same way, so you aren't really getting ARM memory model or performance.
There's actually no good reason to use ARM AVDs as of now other than not having an x86 native binary